# Google Chrome, font size 1px smaller than other browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

In chrome the font appears to be 1px smaller than FF and IE and I cannot see why. The font used is "Georgia" and there are no specific browser commands in the CSS or HTML so I cannot figure out why chrome is displaying it different.

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks.

Comment: I never noticed that. Great observation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be based on various factors.  Chrome and Firefox use different font rendering engines, and they also differ in how they interpret ClearType font settings within Windows.  As well, different browsers apply different default CSS styles to unmarked documents which can cause discrepancies in font-size, among other things.  You could try using something like a CSS Reset stylesheet to possibly quell some of the problems, http://www.cssreset.com/ but there's no guarantee that will fix it.

Comment: Hey, I have a reset at the top of the CSS file as it stands with the errors with the font. I can't understand where it comes from as I have never had this problem before to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to achieve the same style for every browser, you should try this:

[sitewizard](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml)

it helped me a lot when i came across the issue. Maybe there is a more elegant solution for the problem but this works definetly.

Comment: The problem occurs with chrome and firefox, but the most up to date version of the browser. It looks like some quirk with chrome but I have never come across this before.

Answer (score 0):

Text will always differ somewhat between different browsers, and between different systems. Even the same browser on the same operating system may give different results, as there are text rendering settings in the system that may affect the apperance

Also, font sizes aren't really measured in pixels, but in points, so there might be a difference in how browsers translate pixel sizes to points.